# "Unresolved function or method require()" when using Babel

Tags: require, babeljs

I am studying Babel recently, and I followed the steps I found in [GitHub](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/zh-Hans/user-handbook.md), everything goes on the right way, I wrote some arrow function, and I get the right result, but when I tried to create class, some problems occurred, I don't know how to handle it.
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSxt4.png)

I was informed that the "**unresolved function or method require()**"

Does it mean I forgot to do something, First I thought maybe I need load requirejs.js, but it did work too, I search the question, but I can't find the solution, so is there someone can help me?

my code is

```
const square = n => n * n;

var a = 2000;

class SSPageController{

    showPage(){

    }
}
```

and the result code is

```
"use strict";
var _classCallCheck2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck");
var _classCallCheck3 = _interopRequireDefault(_classCallCheck2);
var _createClass2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/createClass");
var _createClass3 = _interopRequireDefault(_createClass2);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }



var square = function square(n) {
  return n * n;
};

var a = 2000;

var SSPageController = function () {
  function SSPageController() {
    (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, SSPageController);
  }

  (0, _createClass3.default)(SSPageController, [{
    key: "showPage",
    value: function showPage() {}
  }]);
  return SSPageController;
}();
```

Comment: Just to confirm: this is in a Node environment, right...?

Comment: It's a non-Node.js environments, I want to use Babel in browsers

Comment: If it needs to run in a browser, you'd need to use Webpack to make a browser bundle. Browsers don't know about modules.